# How to use custom CSS in an Odoo 10 POS addon

Tags: css, odoo-10

My custom CSS isn't being loaded when I launch the POS app, but it's loaded into web.assets_backend.1.css in the dashboard. My custom Javascript is being loaded correctly. Is this the correct way to load the CSS? Thanks for your help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_backend" inherit_id="web.assets_backend" name="donation_assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/donation/static/src/css/donation.css" />

                <script type="text/javascript" src="/donation/static/src/js/donation.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/donation/static/src/js/jquery.sglide.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/donation/static/src/js/sGlide.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/donation/static/src/js/donation_frontend.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Javascript and CSS are now being added to the point_of_sale.assets files. It turns out that my QWeb template file in static/src/xml/ had errors which caused some of the Odoo app files to not be found. It might also be the reason why Odoo didn't update web.assets_backend.js and the point_of_sale.assets js and css files.

Here's my updated XML assets file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="assets" inherit_id="point_of_sale.assets" name="donation assets">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/donation/static/lib/jquery.sglide.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/donation/static/lib/sGlide.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/donation/static/src/js/donation.js"></script>
        </xpath>

        <xpath expr="//link[@id='pos-stylesheet']" position="after">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/donation/static/src/css/donation.css" />
        </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but did you add the `point_of_sale` module in the dependencies of your `donation` module?

If not add `"depends" : ["point_of_sale"],` to the dict in your `_openerp_.py`. Add more dependencies if needed.

Now the `point_of_sale` module and it's assets gets loaded first.

**Edit**: Try `inherit_id="point_of_sale.assets"` instead of `inherit_id="web.assets_backend"`. That could do it for you.

Comment: I've changed the inherit_id (it already had point_of_sale listed as a dependency), but Odoo is still adding my Javascript to web.assets_backend and it's using outdated code. I've tried restarting the server, upgrading the module, and even uninstalling and reinstalling the module.

Comment: Could you try it in a blank database?

Comment: I created a new database and it didn't make a difference. I was able to get my Javascript and CSS to show up in point_of_sale.assets once, though. I also keep getting 404s for files in the Odoo apps that are fixed only if I delete the folder of my custom module. Does it make a difference that I'm running Odoo from the source?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the path of css file in three places.

1.`inherit_id="web.assets_backend"`
2.`inherit_id="web.assets_frontend"`
3.`inherit_id="point_of_sale.assets"`

In the templates which inherites the above templates.
The code is shown below.

```
<template id="assets_backend" name="sub_menu assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/pos_update/static/src/css/mypos.css"/>
        </xpath>
    </template>

    <template id="assets_frontend" name="sub_menu assets front" inherit_id="web.assets_frontend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/pos_update/static/src/css/mypos.css"/>
        </xpath>
    </template>

<data>
    <template id="assets" inherit_id="point_of_sale.assets">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/pos_update/static/src/css/mypos.css"/>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/pos_update/static/src/js/cancel.js"></script>

        </xpath>
    </template>
</data>
```

You also need to ensure that if you want to modify an existing template then the stylesheet name must not be changed.

If you want to create a stylesheet for your template the you only need to set the path of stylesheet in only one place, ie in the main template file in which you are setting the path of js file.

```
<template id="assets" inherit_id="point_of_sale.assets">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/pos_update/static/src/css/mypos.css"/>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/pos_update/static/src/js/cancel.js"></script>

            </xpath>
        </template>
```